# What is the simplest way to assign a Java program its own command?

Tags: java, kotlin, command-line, jvm, command-line-interface

**I'm creating a CLI program in Kotlin (Java). I want to bind the main function/class to an individual command, such as `program`.**

However, from what I searched online, it seems like the only way to run a Java program is with the command `java`. For example, `java -jar program.jar args`, or `java -cp "..." Program args`. But they are very inconvenient for users to type every time, which I experienced when I used [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a command-line repository cleaner tool written in Java.

I could use an alias, but there is no standard way to add aliases to a system when users install my CLI program. For example, most people use Bash, so I have to install the alias to `.bashrc` or `.profile`, but others might use `zsh` or `csh`, which don't read `.profile`.

I could also wrap it with a native program, but I'll need to write that in a native language just to redirect the commands, which I might as well just rewrite the entire thing in that language.

In Node.js, developers can simply specify their command in their `package.json` and everyone who installed this package through `npm i -g` can use the command. What is the simplest alternative to this in JVM languages?

Comment: Just create the script, wrap your `java` call inside, and pass arguments if there are any. Then, make sure to put your script on `PATH`. It should do.

Comment: @Oo.oO Then the command would have to be something like `program.sh`? That's fine, and in my installer, should I put the script along with my `.jar` in a universal `/bin` folder like `/usr/local/bin`? or should I leave them where they are and modify `$PATH`?

Comment: If you're building your project with Gradle, the easiest way is to use the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd have organised things following way:

```
your_app
|-- Hello.java
|-- bin
|   `-- hello.sh
`-- lib
    `-- hello.jar
```

Inside `Hello.java` there is a simple code:

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    if(arg.length > 0) {
      System.out.println("Hello: " + arg[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

and you can build it like this:

```
> javac Hello.java
> jar cf lib/hello.jar Hello.class
```

*Note that for simplicity I do it ugly way. You should definitely look at something called `Manifest` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html*

Then, inside `hello.sh` you can put something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

export HELLO_LOCATION=${HELLO_LOCATION:-$(cd $(dirname $0)/.. ; pwd)

java -cp $HELLO_LOCATION/lib/hello.jar Hello $*
```

Once everything is in place, you are free to put `your_app` anywhere in the file system. All you have to do (to get it visible), is to put `hello.sh` on `PATH`. So, you tell people to do:

```
export PATH=${SOME_LOCATION}/your_app/bin:${PATH}
```

Since now, everybody can do:

```
> hello.sh hello
Hello: hello
```

You may also (for the convenience) create symbolic link inside `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

If you plan to release multiple version of your code, it's worth looking at something called: [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net).

You can read about them here: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/

Sample targets `macOS` but will do for `Linux` as well.

Comment: Mmm, that's probably the standard approach.  But there's no need for the `.sh` extension; most installed commands don't use it.  Remember that shells use the first line of a file, not its filename, to work out how to execute it.  (Many programs you've installed via a package manager, or even part of the system, are actually driver scripts rather than machine-code executables!)

Comment: That's true. `.sh` can be omitted. I, personally, prefer to keep `.sh` just to make user aware of the fact that he/she is actually running shell script. But that's `100%` true it's not required.

Comment: One reason _not_ to use `.sh` is that you might want to change the driver script into a machine-code executable, or some other type of file.  And if there _were_ a reason why the user needed to know what type of file they were running, more files would use one…  For example, `/usr/bin` on this Mac turns out to have about 600 Mach-O executables, 70 shell scripts, 160 Perl scripts, and a handful of Python, Ruby, PHP, and dtrace — very few of which have any extension!